# can I Save & access Data from apple iCloud just like i Use to have from other private webserver?

Tags: ios, icloud

Following is general knowledge question for my owns awareness, actually I am new to iOS programming, in my very first app I used to save access a json file and photos which I placed in a free webserver, but I am not sure about how many days I can acquire benefits from that feee web server. hence I was planing to purchase a web-domain & web-space, meanwhile I come to know about apple icloud storage, so the question is that can I save same json file & other image files at icloud  and can access in same way as I used to save & access at private web server? and also willing to know, how much data can be transfer (total traffic consumption of data on daily basis and monthly basis)?

Comment: you could purchase a a amazon web server. it is free for 12 months provided you have a credit card.

Answer (score 0):

1)You can access the icloud file :

```
NSArray *tempArray=[[iCloud sharedCloud] listCloudFiles];
```

2)To Download :

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

if (ubiq == nil) {
    return NO;
}

NSError *theError = nil;

[fm setUbiquitous:true itemAtURL:backupUrl destinationURL:[[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents" isDirectory:true] URLByAppendingPathComponent:backupName] error:&theError];

    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

if (ubiq == nil) {
    return NO;
}

NSError *theError = nil;

bool started = [fm startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:[[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents" isDirectory:true] URLByAppendingPathComponent:backupName] error:&theError];

NSLog(@"started download for %@ %d", backupName, started);

if (theError != nil) {
    NSLog(@"iCloud error: %@", [theError localizedDescription]);
}
```